# create a menu drop down menu from button in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, xcode5, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that is correctly configured and running. let's say the class of this controller is called : tableViewController. On this table, i have a `UIBarButton` present on the left of the view created like this :

```
UIBarButtonItem *userProfile = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(userProfileGo:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = userProfile;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I already created another view controller called `userProfileViewController`, in which the user can access their profile, it is already configured and pushed on userProfileGo this way :

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"userProfile" sender: self];
```

What i want to do , is show up the user profile ViewController when clicked over the tableViewController as a small window

this picture represents my goal :

[image]

Is there any possible way to do that ?

Comment: You can use the modal style to present it.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/remenu or https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=menu

Comment: How about using a slide controller instead ?? Becomes easier to handle ..

Comment: +1 to REMenu I have used it and is pretty similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: or use a popoverViewController on the UIButton. this isn't windows, no one wants to see drop downs on their iphones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea in mind, but relating to the low performance it had and iOS users weren't comfortable with it, I started looking for new ideas and I found this library on GitHub

- [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)

which looks like this:

[image]

This is not related to the answer, but it's just a suggestion I wanted to give to you.

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `UIPopoverController+iPhone.h` for any PopOverView in iPhone also (or) like a dropdown menuView from `UIBarButtonItem` Ref answer from :[UIPopoverController for iphone not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787765/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-not-working)

also if you need like Sliding Menu means you can use `SWRevealViewController` Ref : https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

also you can Refer : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mlppopupmenu

Also you can call Instance of That `menuViewController` and add view of that ViewController like `[self.View addSubView:menuViewController.View];` by setting the frame with Origin.

Let me know once if it worked or any Queries.