# Why storyboard popover not working on device in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

I have crated popover using storyboard, it working fine on simulator, 
But I am getting error on device, app get crash on device while popover

I am testing this on IOS7 device

Is there any solution for that?

The error message :

> Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values

Comment: check object returns as nil object thats why this error occur

Comment: yes have check, but its working fine on simulator, but not on device, may be its device issue

Comment: i think it is about your linked frameworks, do you use any?

Comment: Please paste the code

Comment: Are you attempting to use a UIPopover on an iPhone ?  If so, Apple reckons they're not supported:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787765/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Popovers  not supported on the iPhone in iOS 7. You will need iOS 8 for the iPhone to support popovers.