# How to create popup using sprite kit on iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, popup, sprite-kit

I am a beginner developing an iOS game using sprite kit. I would like to have 'pop-up' menu's that display objects (skspritenodes) such as daily rewards or settings/pause menu. The settings pop-up for example should be able to be accessed on the main home screen or during the game. Currently I have one view controller and the home scene and play scene are two different SKScenes. For reusability (and a clean project, as well as learning) I would like to have these pop-ups be their own class, including handling touches. Currently, I have a class for the settings pop-up that returns an SKNode, and this sknode contains several skspritenodes (the buttons/images that correspond to a settings pop up including enabling/disabling sound etc). However, I have to duplicate the touches code in both my home scene and my play scene to interact with this. (I currently have, in each skscene's touchesbegan method, "if nodeSettings !=nil", check the name of the skspritenode that corresponds to the touch-location, then call a method in the setting-pop-up class passing the name of the skspritenode clicked to handle interactions with the pop-up).

For my own knowledge and also to solve this problem, I would like to use a class that can handle the touch logic on its own (so in my play or home skscene, the only thing I do is create the pop-up. Any interaction, including dismissal, I would like to have handled in the class. No using the skscene's touches methods). I have found one 'solution' to this:

```
LTPopUpReward *test = [[LTPopUpReward alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:test];
CGFloat fltHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGFloat fltWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(fltWidth/2, fltHeight/2); //your custom size.
CGRect rectPopUpReward = CGRectMake(500, 500, fltWidth/2, fltHeight/2);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:rectPopUpReward inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

and I like that you can dismiss the UIPopoverController by clicking outside of it, but this UIPopoverController only works on the iPad and doesn't work on the iPhone. I've seen this [UIPopoverController for iphone not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787765/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-not-working) but was wondering if there is another way to solve my problem that Apple won't possibly disapprove of? For example, could I create a UIViewController, resize it and position it (i don't know how to do this) to simulate the pop-up?

Summarizing: my goal is to have a pop-up appear, but have all of its code (including touch) self contained within one class, and the objects on the pop-up are skspritenodes.

Comment: You can't do that. Your SKScene handles all touch methods and you cannot pick and choose which nodes are affected by this.

Answer (score 2):

answering my own question: The solution I used to solve this problem is to use different SKViews. One SKView presents the main scene and another SKView presents the pop-up scene. You can adjust the size of the second SKView and even make its background transparent. Interacting with objects in this view will correctly call the touches methods in the class of the scene presented - That is this pop-up is dealt with when being created, and there is no other code dealing with it on the view-controller or main-scene's logic (all code, including creating objects and handling touch) are in the second skscene's code. The method below is called when I do "something" to call the 'pop-up'.

```
-(void)test4
{
    skViewPopUp=nil;
    scenePopUpReward=nil;
    NSLog(@"test4 successfully fired");
    CGFloat fltHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat fltWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGRect rectPopUpReward = CGRectMake(0, 0, fltWidth/2, fltHeight/2);
    skViewPopUp = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:rectPopUpReward];
    [self.view addSubview:skViewPopUp];
    skViewPopUp.allowsTransparency = YES;
    scenePopUpReward = [[LTSceneStoreMain alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(fltWidth/2, fltHeight/2)];
    scenePopUpReward.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [skViewPopUp presentScene:scenePopUpReward];
}
```