# UIPopoverController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8.4

Everybody says `UIPopoverController` work on iOS 8.

But if i test my app in iPhone simulator it getting crashed and log says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController
>   initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under
>   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'

This code works fine on iPad simulator.

My `Development Target` set to 8.4

```
UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyleMenu" bundle:nil];
    self.stylePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    self.stylePopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,200);
    [self.stylePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:styleBarButton
                               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                               animated:YES];
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UIPopoverController works in iPad only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible starting from iOS8. I have already gave answer to similar question and even implemented a useful class to work with popovers on iPhone and even put some custom elements there, such as `UITableView`, `WKWebView`, you name it.
You can check out my answer and link to class here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418212/2924920

Comment: your code seems really nice, BUT how can i use it with `UIBarButtonItem` ?where i have not any `sourceView` and `sourceRect` .

Comment: Easy. Just use this code:  

    `- (IBAction)didTapBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    // Configure, as in my example first, then do this:
        popoverController.sourceView = nil;
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(sender.width, CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds), 0, 0);
    // Further configurations, as in my example afterwards...
    }`

Comment: ok that worked, but do you have any problem with device rotation? when i rotate to landscape the `popOver` won't show correctly. any help with that?

Answer (score 2):

`UIPopoverController` is unavailable on the iPhone. Use the new `popoverPresentationController` property of your viewController instead

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html

```
MYViewController * myViewController = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
myViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = button;
myViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = button.bounds;
[self presentViewController: myViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: tnx, this works fine, BUT if i use it with `UIBarButtonItem` like     `viewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = styleBarButton;` then how to set `sourceRect` ? if i don't set this the popover fill the entire screen!

Comment: The `sourceRect` is where the arrow points. To set the size you'll need to set the `preferredContentSize` property of your view controller

Comment: ok, `viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,200);` will not work and `viewController.popoverPresentationController.preferredContentSize`is readonly property. so how can i set the size?

Comment: Is your view controller inside a `UINavigationController`? If so you'll need to set the `preferredContentSize` of that

Comment: yes, but `self.navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,200);` won't work either. please note that i create viewController with a nib file. and `viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,200);` works fine on iPad, but in iPhone the entire screen will filled.

Answer (score 0):

[Unfortunately the UIPopoverController is exclusive for iPads, as per the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/initWithContentViewController:)

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

Also a possible duplicate from this question?
[UIPopoverController for iphone not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787765/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-not-working)

Comment: We can use `UIPopoverPresentationController` for in iPhone from iOS 8 it's available.